# Using an array of Booleans to select specific indices for transformation

Tags: arrays, swift, functional-programming, boolean

I am trying to use an array of Booleans as a mechanism for transforming specific indices in another identically sized array of Ints while ignoring the indices that contain a false in the corresponding selection array.

Basically, I want this function to only transform the values that contain a 'true' in the corresponding boolean selection array and leave the others as they already are.

Here's how I managed to (sort of) get it to work using a for loop.

However, I'd like to know how to do this in a more functional style.  I'm also open to being told that this is absolutely foolish and I should try another way. I had some success using a zip function to create a tuple at each recursion but I'd like to see how experts do it.

I'd like to see if it is possible using a map instead of an ugly for loop like I did here.

```
func changeSelectedChannels(_ newVal: UInt8, forChannels selections: [Bool], array oldArray: [UInt8]) -> [UInt8] {
    var j = 0
    var newArray = oldArray
    for index in selections{
        if index == true{
            newArray[j] = newVal
            j += 1
        }else{
            j += 1
        }
    } 
    return newArray   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result with [`zip()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) and [`map()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018371-map):

```
func changeSelectedChannels(_ newVal: UInt8, forChannels selections: [Bool], array oldArray: [UInt8]) -> [UInt8] {
    let newArray = zip(oldArray, selections).map {
        (oldVal, flag) in flag ? newVal : oldVal
    }
    return newArray
}
```

The closure is called with all pairs (one element from `oldArray` and the corresponding element from `selections`), and returns either the old array value or `newVal`.

Another possible solution is to use [`enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated)  to get rid of the `j` index variable:

```
func changeSelectedChannels(_ newVal: UInt8, forChannels selections: [Bool], array oldArray: [UInt8]) -> [UInt8] {
    var newArray = oldArray
    for (idx, flag) in selections.enumerated() where flag {
        newArray[idx] = newVal
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: I tried it and it worked perfectly.  

I'm going to be asking a much more complex question in a few minutes about making this functionality into a struct and class.  I'd love to get more help from you.  Sincerely appreciated!